# Saving downloaded zip file to local file

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, stream

I'm trying to save a zip file stream that I've downloaded from a server.
Now I've the `Stream` But I'm not able to save to a file. here is my attempt =>

```
 private async Task DownloadCompleted(Stream inputStream, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var file = await _downloadFolder.CreateFileAsync(_productDescription.ProductFileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting, ct);
        using (Stream str = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccess.ReadAndWrite, ct))
        {
            await inputStream.CopyToAsync(str);
        }
     }
```

I'm trying to do it `Xamarin.Android` Project, I'm not good at streams, Also some good pointer are highly appreciated.

Edit- here I got the stream

```
  private async Task DownloadFileFromUrl(string url, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        try
        {
            var receivedBytes = 0;
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            using (var stream = await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(url))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[4096];
                var totalBytes = int.Parse(client.ResponseHeaders[HttpResponseHeader.ContentLength]);

                for (;;)
                {
                    var bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, ct);
                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                    {
                        await Task.Yield();
                        break;
                    }
                    receivedBytes += bytesRead;
                    if (_downloadProgressHandler != null)
                    {
                        _downloadProgressHandler((int)(((double)receivedBytes / totalBytes) * 100), false);
                    }
                }
                await DownloadCompleted(stream, ct);
            }
        }
        catch (System.OperationCanceledException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Analytics.AddHandledExceptionEvent(ex, "Ex-ProductDownloader-DownloadFileFromUrl");
            throw new NetworkNotAvailableException("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you've got some code you've tried... and what happens?

Comment: @JonSkeet It's not copied correctly, when I tried to unzip this file, it throws exception, Most probably it's not copied correctly..

Comment: So you should look at the file in detail - is it the right size compared with the original file? What exception is thrown when you try to unzip it? If you have the original file, are they the same to start with and then differ? You need to try to diagnose this yourself first, and then include the information in your question.